# Modifying this Script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, png, transparent, fade

I found this script on this site which helps to fadeIn/Out transparent .png's in IE without the transparent part being filled in with black during the fade effect:

```
var i;
  for (i in document.images) {
    if (document.images[i].src) {
        var imgSrc = document.images[i].src;
        if (imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.png' || imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.PNG') {
            document.images[i].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='" + imgSrc + "')";
        }
    }
}
```

This script was created by [this stackoverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425741/garciawebdev) and it works perfectly well on my site. However, I want to modify it a little bit. This script finds ALL .png files on my page and applies the filter. However, this may be causing performance issues because I have many transparent .png files on my site, yet I only need to apply this filter to one of them. It's a fixed position menu DIV background image that fades in and fades out using jQuery while the page is scrolling.

Can someone help me to modify this script so that I can just provide it with one image or use getElementById("menu") and have it apply this filter.  Nothing I have tried seems to work and putting the filter in my CSS didn't work either, so the javascript way seems to be the way to go. I just need to use it on one .png, not all of them.

Remember this is the background image of the div #menu, so the image itself has no ID, though of course the div does. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The idea of stack overflow is not to provide code but to bring about specific programming problems/questions. If you want to edit it a little and have a problem or you've lost your way in doing so then please advise us other wise.

Comment: I thought that that was what I had done. I've lost my way trying to edit that code myself so I came here hoping that a more experienced coder would find my problem simple and be able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, [document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) returns a collection of the `img` elements, so if it's `background-image`, that wouldn't work.  However, if it's an `img` that being used in the background it will work. If you're just going to apply it to one image whose ID you know, then it'd be

```
function applyFilterToImageById(id) {
    var i,
        parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    for (i in parentElement.images) {
    if (document.images[i].src) {
        var imgSrc = document.images[i].src;
        if (imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.png' || imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.length-4) === '.PNG') {
            document.images[i].style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled='true',sizingMethod='crop',src='" + imgSrc + "')";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi saml, thanks for the quick answer.  I assume you meant a period after ('menu') not a semi-colon.  Either way, that doesn't seem to work. Remember, the image in question is the background image (set in css) of the #menu div. I've tried things such as "var image = document.getElementById("menu").style.background;" but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Ah, I don't think what you're asking is possible, because a `background-image` isn't an html element, and can't be styled like one.

Comment: I thought that there must be some way to reference that image, since the original script in my first post works perfectly for that background image. I just wanted to streamline it a little bit because there are so many .png files on my page, but I only need that script for the one...

Comment: IE8.  FF and Chrome have no problem with or without the script.

Comment: FF and Chrome has image transparency support built in. IE8 requires this, and it's deprecated for IE9.  Beyond that, I'm not sure.  I dont' use Windows and don't have access to IE.

Comment: That's okay, I'll just stick with the script I have, even if it's doing extra work, at least it works right! Thanks for your help and your time :)